# Windows Event Log Source when logging in dotNet Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

How do I specify the windows event log source when using the dotNet core logging framework?

I'm able to log to the Windows EventLog but it is unclear how I specify the Source for the log entry.

Answer (score 6):

As of .NET 3.x, an [`EventLog` is automatically added to the configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Host.cs#L112-L116) when running on Windows, thus instead of adding another Event Log, you should just configure the `EventLogSettings` for the existing `EventLog`, in order to set your Source name.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<EventLogSettings>(settings =>
            {
                settings.SourceName = "NameOfYourEventSource";
            });

            // ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the appropriate properties of the [`EventLogSettings` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventlog.eventlogsettings) you pass to the `AddEventLog()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
    {
        SourceName = "YourSourceName"
    });
}
```

Comment: This for ASP.NET core or .NET framework? If core, please specify packages used and references.

Comment: @Joey all those things are explained at the link in my answer. It's Core, and the assembly is `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll`. But the answer is three months old already, they probably renamed it in the meantime.

Comment: @CodeCaster, from what I have seen, asp.net core does not support logging to event viewer, thats why I was asking. The Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll is for full .NET framework, not core

Comment: It is supported- you just have to install a package (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#windows-eventlog-provider