# Entity Framework Core 3.1 SaveChangesAsync() automatically logs exceptions to Windows Event Viewer

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have my custom logger service which uses some stored procedure to log details into database. I have disabled default EF Core loggers.

When I get any exception from `SaveChangesAsync`, it is automatically being logged to windows event viewer.

```
try
{
    await _dbContent.SaveChangesAsync(data); // At this line a log is written into windows event viewer when any exception occurs
}
catch (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException ex)     {
    // loggerService.LogError(ex);
}
```

Here is the screenshot of windows event viewer

[image]

I do not want to log to windows event viewer as my custom logger service is already the same.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro in your question?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The SaveChangesAsyc() method is giving exception for null column. This exception is automatically getting logged into windows event viewer which I don't want it to happen

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro in your question?  EF Core 3 doesn't write to the Windows Event log by default.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This links says that Windows Event log is enabled by default in EF Core 3.x https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206952/3678363

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is being logged because it is not caught by your application. In your try-catch you are catching a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException`, but the event log shows that your code is throwing `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. They are not the same thing, so the exception is not caught and therefore logged in the event log.  I suggest you catch `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

Comment: I even tried with the base class Exception. Even there it is logging into windows event viewer

Comment: It only goes to the EventLog if you allow the application to crash with an unhandled exception.